# Reading array of struct from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct, upgrading

I have a contract that stores some struct array in it like:

```
contract MyContract{
  struct DataStruct {
      uint256 data1;
      uint32 data2;
  }
  DataStruct [] dataStructs;
}
```

Now i'm going to replace it with new version but the data in it is valuable for me. What are my best options to migrate data from old contract to the new one?

Can i read the array from the old contract in new contract's constructor or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's sample code of a solution I (quickly) came up with. It reads in the old struct values and pushes them to a new updated struct with additional members.

Pending on your array size - it might blow up the block gas limit if you try to loop through them all on deployment or even after deployment.

I'd suggest creating batch transactions to do X amount at a time to optimize gas costs.

Contract One:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./Two.sol";

contract One {
    Two two = new Two();

    struct Boxv2 {
        uint256 id;
        bool isFull;
        string name;
    }
    Boxv2[] public boxes;

    constructor() public{
    }

    //test migration 
    function migrateBox(uint _id, string _name) public {
        uint256 id;
        bool isFull;
        (id, isFull) = two.boxes(_id);
        boxes.push(Boxv2(id, isFull, _name));
    }

    //test returning tuples
    function getOldBox(uint _id) public view returns (uint256, bool) {
        return two.boxes(_id);
    }
}
```

Contract Two:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Two{

    struct Box {
        uint256 id;
        bool isFull;
    }
    Box[] public boxes;

    constructor() public {
        boxes.push(Box(0, false));
        boxes.push(Box(1, true));
    }
}
```